# How to solve IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable in list comprehension statement? Python 3.7.7

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to finish writing an algorithm for a class. I'm trying to create a list, value, in which each element is the summation of two other numbers. Here's the line that is giving me trouble:

```
value = [Q_hat_cluster[cluster][i] + U_hat_cluster[cluster][i] for i in range(5)]
```

I keep getting **IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable** errors. Here's the full error message :

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/-----/Documents/Python Related/practice.py", line 38
    U_hat_cluster[cluster] = np.sqrt((alpha * np.log(t))/(2 * num_pulls[cluster][arm-1]))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/----/Documents/Python Related/practice.py", line 38
    U_hat_cluster[cluster] = np.sqrt((alpha * np.log(t))/(2 * num_pulls[cluster][arm-1]))
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/----/Documents/Python Related/practice.py", line 45, in <module>
    segmentUCB()
  File "/Users/----/Documents/Python Related/practice.py", line 31, in segmentUCB
    value.append(Q_hat_cluster[cluster][i] + U_hat_cluster[cluster][i])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Q_hat_cluster and U_hat_cluster are dictionaries with keys 1,2,3,4 and values np.ones(5) and np.zeros(5), respectively. (e.g., Q_hat_cluster = {1: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]), 2: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])...}.

Cluster is essentially random.choice([1,2,3,4]) (it's not actually, prof used some other complex probability stuff to generate instances of cluster)

I'm trying to add the ith value from the given cluster key from Q_hat_cluster and U_hat_cluster together. Then move onto the next element. I'm confused because I can access U_hat_cluster[cluster][i] and Q_hat_cluster[cluster][i] no problem. I even wrote a mini for loop to see if indexing was the problem:

```
    for i in range(5):
        print(Q_hat_cluster[1][i] + U_hat_cluster[1][i])
```

and it printed it correctly, no problem.  Any ideas for fixing this error?

Comment: What's the output of `print(repr(cluster))` and `print(type(cluster))` right before that list comprehension? Also, please always copy/paste the full stack trace, not just the error part, you're removing information that can be used to help you for no good reason.

Comment: @Boris `print(repr(cluster))` outputs 4 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0. `print(type(cluster))` outputs `<class 'int'>` 4 times. Thanks for the advice, I'll update the question shortly

Comment: how can the `repr` of `cluster` be `1.0` if it's type is `int`? A `repr` of an integer can't have decimal places, it should be just `1`. Are you modifying `Q_hat_cluster` in this loop? Can you print them before the list comprehension just to check that they are actually dictionaries of numpy arrays?

Comment: By "print them" I mean what's the output of `print(Q_hat_cluster)` and `print(U_hat_cluster)` right before the list comprehension? I guess you changed it from a list comprehension to a `for` loop.